# android java string operation

Tags: java, equivalent

What is the equivalent Java for this PHP code?

```
//print string plus/with variable     
$mystring = "this is string " .$string

//print sum one + two
$count = $one + $two

//print sum one*two
$count = $one * $two
```

Comment: For those people who know java but not php, what does the code do?

Comment: What does this have to do with android?

Comment: @azurefrog i just want to know how to run this operation on java

Comment: this is a php code, are you trying to convert it to java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like :

```
String mystring= "this is string " + string; // here `string` is aloso  String  object

/*
* if count ,one and two all of them are int
*/
int count = one + two;

int count = one * two;
```

But i would suggest to learn basics of java  before starting android. As you know php it will not take long to learn java syntax.

Comment: No, they are not `java.lang.Integer`. They are primitive `int`.

Comment: mistakenly mixed up thanks for pointing. @LittleChild

Comment: You are welcome! :) +1 for the correction.